# Validação de log-in por vetor (array) .java

Tags: java

Estou estudando vetores em orientação a objetos e decidi fazer um programinha para por em prática algumas coisas.

Ele consiste em fazer o cadastro de **n** vetores que serão contas bancárias com *name, password, account e balance*. Usando apenas o console como interação, devem ser cadastradas em posições no vetor separadamente cada `new conta(name,password,account,balance)`.

Logo após, deve-se pedir uma espécie de "*log-in"* que consiste em *name e password* e ambas devem passar num processo básico e rústico de validação, que seria primeiramente ver se o *name* digitado na parte de *log-in* corresponde a uma conta cadastrada no vetor e se a resposta for *true* dar a opção dele digitar o *password*, e a validação deste será ver se o vetor com o *name* escolhido tem a *password* cadastrado igualmente a que o usuário digitou no *log-in*.

```
package application;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

import entities.ContaBancaria;

public class ProgramContaBancaria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Digite quantas contas serão cadastradas: ");
        int quantidade = sc.nextInt();
        ContaBancaria[] conta = new ContaBancaria[quantidade];

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < conta.length; i++) {
        int x = 1;
        x += i; 
        System.out.println("Conta #"+ x);
        System.out.print("Digite o nome da conta para cadastro: ");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Digite a senha para cadastro: ");
        int password = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Digite o número da conta para cadastro: ");
        int account = sc.nextInt();
        conta[i] = new ContaBancaria(name, password, account);
        System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Clientes cadastrados com sucesso!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("  Login");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = sc.next();
        boolean check = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < conta.length; i++) {
            if(conta[i].getName().equals(name) ) {
                    check = true;
            }
            else 
                    check = false;
            }

            if (check = true) {
            System.out.print("Password: ");
            }
            else if (check = false){
                System.out.print("Nome inválido: ");
                String name2 = sc.next();
                name += name2;
        }
        int password = sc.nextInt();

    }

}
```

Aí que está o problema, o compilador não está "respeitando" a condição `if(check = false){sysout("Nome inválido");}(...)`.

Independente do que eu faça ou digite ele dá como `true` e já executa o `sysout{("Password: );}`.

O que está errado? O que eu poderia fazer para melhorar/mudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro não tem nada a ver com "o compilador não estar respeitando a condição". Na verdade o programa está fazendo exatamente o que você pediu.

No caso, o trecho `if(check = true)` está fazendo o seguinte:

- atribuindo o valor `true` na variável `check`
- testando esse valor

É como se você fizesse em 2 etapas:

```
check = true;
if (check) {
    ....
```

Sim, repare que, quando a variável é um `boolean`, eu não preciso compará-la com `true` ou `false`. O `if` testa um valor booleano, e como a própria variável `check` é um `boolean`, eu posso verificá-la diretamente. E como o valor é `true`, ele **sempre** vai entrar neste `if`.

Claro que eu poderia verificar se o valor dela é igual a `true`, fazendo `if (check == true)`, mas para variáveis booleanas isso é redundante e desnecessário. De qualquer forma, veja que para comparar valores usamos o operador `==`, e não `=`.

Ou seja, `if (check = true)` faz com que sempre entre neste `if` - e portanto nunca chega no `if (check = false)`.
Aliás, esse `if` também está errado. Se quer testar se um booleano é falso, basta fazer `if (! check)` ("se *check* for falso").

Mas como o booleano só pode ter 2 valores (verdadeiro ou falso), não precisa testar a mesma variável de novo no `else`. Basta fazer assim:

```
if (check) {
    // check é verdadeiro (true)
} else {
    // check é falso (false)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Talvez eu esteja errado, mas creio eu que comparações deve ser feitas com `==` e não apenas `=`:

```
if(check == false)
```

`==` => Comparação

`=`  => Atribuir valor